# Mocking WebapplicationContext in Junit test case

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mocking

I am trying to run a Junit test case for a method which uses webapplication context internally. However my problem is that I can not create or mock WebApplicationContext in Junit. When application is build and run then the actual code executes fine and webapplication context is created but in Junit it can not create the same.

My test case has below tags

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationcontext.xml")
```

The method which I am trying to test has below code

```
WebApplicationContext context = 
ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
context.getBean("checkStatus", checkStatus.class);
```

At this point I get null pointer exception as it can not get webapplication context from ContextLooader, Can I mock this some how so that it does not give null pointer or some how can I get the actual webapplication context so that I can use it.

Should I add some code for WebApplicationContext loading in my application context xml file. In my web.xml file there is an entry regarding ContextLoaderListener should I read configuration from web.xml also in my Junit Test case?

Please provide some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

there's a lot missing from you question, including details of your environment, version numbers, and especially the exact problem you're trying to solve.

we run junit and spring boot flawlessly using the instructions in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server .

but since we have no information about your use case, i can't tell whether that would work for you or not.